# How to keep the back color of the cell after passing the highlight at the top of that cell?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, css, gridview

I have a GridView that give some cells specific back color which is Green. Now, I am using a JQuery for fixing the Header and the Columns. This JQuery has a highlighter. The problem now is when the highlighter goes on the top of those cells that have green back color, the green back color will be disappeared and the cell will has no color after the highlighter leave this cell.

The following image shows you the problem:
[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                sh_highlightDocument();

                $(".tableDiv").each(function () {
                    var Id = $(this).get(0).id;
                    var maintbheight = 555;
                    var maintbwidth = 900;

                    $("#" + Id + " .FixedTables").fixedTable({
                        width: maintbwidth,
                        height: maintbheight,
                        fixedColumns: 4,
                        classHeader: "fixedHead",
                        classFooter: "fixedFoot",
                        classColumn: "fixedColumn",
                        fixedColumnWidth: 500,
                        outerId: Id,
                        Contentbackcolor: "#FFFFFF",
                        Contenthovercolor: "#99CCFF",
                        fixedColumnbackcolor: "#187BAF",
                        fixedColumnhovercolor: "#99CCFF"
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>
```

I am using this [JQuery FixedTable](http://www.bluelemoncode.com/post/2011/12/30/Freezing-gridview-header-and-columns-while-scrolling-rest-of-the-content.aspx)

Comment: Can you post a link to the fixedTable plugin you use? It is possible that you will need to modify that plugin or find a different one if you cannot hook into it's hover behaviour enough to restore the previous background colour.

Comment: see the link at the end of my question.

Comment: There is no super easy way to modify the behaviour of that plugin without adding a few extra lines into the source to save the existing background colour on mouseover (use `$.data()`) and restore it on mouseout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the existing property of the cell in a variable before you change it.

I am not 100% with JQuery syntax, but if you can do something like:

(onHover)
var oldColor = cell.Style["background-color"];

cell.Style["background-color"] = Green;

(onMouseOut)
cell.Style["background-color"] = oldColor;

That should give you the required functionality